# Switch Magic Keyboard/Magic Mouse/Magic Trackpad from Windows and Mac with dongle

Tags: macos, windows, bluetooth, magic-trackpad, switching

I have a MacBook Pro 2018 (Intel) and a PC with Windows 10 desktop (WiFi card and Bluetooth Fenvi T919).

Being that I often use both and switch between them I wish I could **use my Magic Keyboard, Magic Mouse, and Magic Trackpad on both devices** without having to have 2 mice and 2 keyboards.

All of these devices work great on both Mac and Windows. The trackpad also works great on Windows thanks to [Mac-precision-trackpad](https://github.com/imbushuo/mac-precision-touchpad) from [Imbushuo](https://github.com/imbushuo)

Since I often connect my MacBook to an external monitor I thought of following this procedure to make the transition of my input devices from mac to Windows smooth.

I use this [USB/HDMI switch](https://amzn.to/3aCKIiU) to quickly change which PC to use with the external monitor and connect this [Bluetooth USB](https://amzn.to/3GU9BTf) to it so as to have at the same time the passage of input devices from one computer to another.

I have not found much about this procedure on the net and I would have some doubts:

1. If it works, I suppose the Bluetooth of the Mac and the PC is replaced with that of the dongle but if I unplug the Mac to go out of the house, the Bluetooth of the Mac is automatically reactivated, or do I have to turn it off or do other procedures?
2. If I had to connect other Bluetooth devices ONLY to the Mac such as the AirPods so that they can be used both at home in front of the monitor and on the move in front of the MacBook. Should I connect them both to the key and to the Bluetooth of the Mac? Or is it possible to connect them only to the Mac?
3. Is there a **more effective way to do this** and have the input devices on 2 computers? **(I state that I do not want 2 mice and 2 keyboards and I am not interested in buying Logitech MX or similar devices)**

The key should arrive in days so I can start rehearsing.